# JPype: how to convert the boolean value from python to java

Tags: jpype

I want to run java class in my python code and I use the tool JPype.
I have a java method with a boolean argument.
It works in java code but when I call it in python, I get the error message:

```
RuntimeError: No matching overloads found. at src/native/common/jp_method.cpp:121
```

I even use the jpype wrapper JBoolean, but it still fails.
For example, the code in java is:

```
item.myMethod(true);
```

and I have tried to convert it in python as:

```
item.myMethod(1)
item.myMethod(True)
item.myMethod(jpype.JBoolean(True))
item.myMethod(jpype.JBoolean(1))
```

but all of above get the same error message.
Could anyone help me to convert the boolean argument from python to java??
thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Is the argument of your Java method defined as a `boolean` or a `java.lang.Boolean`?

If it is `boolean`, then all the possibilities you have tried should work (if not there might be something wrong with the way you import the Class in your Python code). However, if it's a `java.lang.Boolean`, then you have to call your method as such:

```
item.myMethod(jpype.java.lang.Boolean(True))
```